# Google Maps Autozoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp-classic

I have the following page, which by defaults opens a map centered on France:

http://www.villasdirect.com/_admin/dev/Country_MapV3.asp

It does seem to auto zoom to a certain extent, however when I look at France or Germany (just a couple of examples) the countries are not zoomed in close enough.  If I search London however, it seems to be pretty much perfect - as in filling the box with a map of London.

You can see the different results here:

http://www.villasdirect.com/_admin/dev/Country_MapV3.asp?l=france

What I am aiming to do is the fill the map with the country, town or region, when selected... possible?

Help appreciated as always!

Here is my code too:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
location = request.QueryString("l")
if location = "" then location = "France"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>

<form onsubmit="showAddress(); return false" action="#">
  <input id="search" size="60" type="hidden" value="<%=location%>" />
</form>

<div id="message"></div>

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[


var xmlsource = '<markers><marker Town="Fayence" Region="Provence - Var" type="green" lng="6.694103" lat="43.624076"/><marker Town="La Cadiere  d\'Azur" Region="Provence - Var" type="green" lng="5.755173" lat="43.196218"/><marker Town="Villefranche Du Périgord" Region="South West France" type="green" lng="1.080006" lat="44.62966"/><marker Town="Limetz-Villez" Region="Paris" type="green" lng="1.547366" lat="49.029137"/><marker Town="Boulogne-Billancourt" Region="Paris" type="green" lng="2.237803" lat="48.84325"/><marker Town="Saint-Germain-En-Laye" Region="Paris" type="green" lng="2.0934031" lat="48.8955155"/></markers>'

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  $( $.parseXML( xmlsource ) ).find("marker").each(function() {
    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002)
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click');

  // ====== Create a Client Geocoder ======
  var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
  geo.geocode({'address': document.getElementById("search").value}, function (results, status) {
     var ne = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
     var sw = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();

     map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport); 
     placeMarkers();              
  }); 

  function placeMarkers(){
    var xmlList = $.parseXML(xmlsource);
    var markers = $(xmlList).find('marker');
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(markers[i]).attr("lat")),
                                parseFloat($(markers[i]).attr("lng")));
    var type = $(markers[i]).attr("type");
    var imgnam = "";
    if(type == "green") {
        imgnam = "http://openmbta.org/images/map/PinDown1Green.png?1306943843";
    }else{
        imgnam = "http://openmbta.org/images/map/PinDown1.png?1306943843";
    }       
    var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        imgnam,
        new google.maps.Size(30,35),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(15,35)
    );
    //add a link to your xml that can be inserted here where I have http://www.google.com
    var html = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>" + $(markers[i]).attr('Region') + ', ' + $(markers[i]).attr('Town') + "</a>";                                  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map, icon: img, html:html});

    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow1.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow1.open(map, this);

    });
    }

  }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but I think I have an answer. Instead of this:

```
map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
```

try this:

```
map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
```

According to Google Maps API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) `results.geometry.bounds` may return a slightly different viewport. It's not exactly a solution, but it's worth a try.

Moreover, as I understand, Google Maps doesn't have imagery at infinite zoom levels and when `fitBounds()` is invoked, it will automatically select the highest zoom level that contains the given bounds ***and*** at which imagery is available. In your case, the bounds are the border of France and the viewport fits the border of France at the current zoom level. If you go just one zoom level further, the boundaries of France go out of the viewport.

You can change the size of viewport. For a certain size of viewport (I can't say exactly what size) you might achieve a perfect fit. You cited an example of London. I'm sure that for certain viewport sizes, London doesn't perfectly fit the viewport either. So, it's by chance that you came across a viewport size that is perfect for London.

If you still want more zoom, and can't change the viewport size, I suggest you try `getZoom()` then increment the result by 1 and `setZoom()`. Then again, that renders the border areas out of the viewport.

Cheerio!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no way of getting the information as to the physical dimensions of an area (be it city/county/country) from google.

If you had a database yourself with the sizes for every city/state/country combo then I guess you could do it with comparisons.

Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck with this one.